# Can a question belong to a user other than the one who originally asked it?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, new-users

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729762/what-is-defaultlayout-tag-in-ui-file) in the First Posts review queue a few hours ago from now (2015/02/26). it was asked by a *seemingly* new comer named **Lina Sellak**!

A few hours later, the question appeared to belong to [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144908/yassir-gourram) who is not a new comer (well, older than me in the SO community)!

The original user is no more on SO, the account was either deleted or blocked.

I wonder if this is a possible functionality (in this case explain it please), or it is a bug  in the system (and has to be corrected)?

Comment: but not only the display name is different! even *member for* period is totally different, this one can't be changed, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user's account was merged into an older account of theirs. This is the only time the system will ever update user IDs on a post. The staff *can* manually change user IDs on a post, but only ever do that to remove it due to a disassociation request.

Comment: if user X is suspended and can't ask question, can he still create a new userID Y, ask a question using Y, then merge it to his X account?

Comment: sorry if my comment is opening another thread! I don't mind to ask it as an independent question. I guess your answer is the best fit for the actual asked question, thus it is accepted