# a work around to ask a question even if you are blocked from doing so!

Tags: discussion, post-ban, gaming-the-system

I learned from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250224/can-a-question-belong-to-a-user-other-than-the-one-who-originally-asked-it) that when user account `Y` is merged into an old user account `X` of the same user, the system will update posts of user `Y` with the user ID `X`.

Now, considering the scenario when user `X` is blocked from asking new questions, he can still register a new account `Y` asks his question, then merge the two accounts into `X` !!

is blocking some users from asking new questions useless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The users can't merge accounts themselves. It can  be made only by mods.

In the case you pointed, I highly doubt that a mod will merge those accounts but just remove the new question and the user, while the first will get a suspension (and a restriction of new questions from this IP).

Comment: A user can actually trigger an automatic merge of accounts under certain circumstances. But I believe the accounts always merge into the oldest account.

Comment: @animuson, what are those certain circumstances?

Comment: @AdamMiller I'm not familiar enough with the merge system to know all the specifics, but I do know that when two accounts have the same login credentials added to them it will trigger an automatic merge process. The merge from the OP's previous question was done by the system, without any intervention from Stack Exchange.