# How can I merge another Stack Exchange Account with my Stack Overflow Account

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I already have an account on Stack Overflow, and have a guest account on Code Review.

I want to know if and how I can merge these two accounts. Any ideas?

Comment: Go to the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), select the "I need to merge user profiles" and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If you sign into your Code Review account using the same OpenID as you used for your Stack Overflow account the system should automatically link the two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that if credentials are the same between two accounts, the system may automatically merge them without human intervention.  It was mentioned on the comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250238/a-work-around-to-ask-a-question-even-if-you-are-blocked-from-doing-so/250239#comment816952_250239), but I do not know the criteria behind that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, only a diamond mod can. You can go to the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and submit a ticket explaining the circumstances.