# Change email login to another id

Tags: support, login

My original email id got compromised and now I want my new email id to be the main id for all SE sites . How to delete original id from the system as someone else might login from it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile page.

There is a "My Logins" link - that allows you to add and delete OpenId providers.

(with the new profile, this will be under the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab)

Comment: will the original stackexchange id then not be able to login ?

Comment: If you remove it, yes. The only way(s) to log in to that account would be with the ones listed under "My Logins".

Comment: Thanks a lot , if I add two SE registered emails under it , would it combine both ?

Comment: @ysts2 - I don't follow? If you add more OpenId providers, they would each be listed and you would be able to log in with either one.

Comment: I meant , I added a new email address (as you suggested) and deleted the compromised one . Thats done and now its safe . I used another SE account to ask this question on meta.SE . So now if I add this SE account in 'My Logins' of the main account's profile , will it combine this and the main one ?

Comment: @ysts2 - no. If they are different, they will not be automatically merged. You can request a merge through the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page.

Comment: Different as in ? And if there is a case of different then whats the case in 'Similar'?

Comment: You say there are two accounts. I am assuming they have different email addresses. So... different.

Comment: Yes . You are correct . Thanks.

Comment: @Oded If possible please have a look over [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250824/286070) since its on similar lines .Thank you .